# Application Activity Logger

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create an event logger in C#. the program has a textbox and at runtime should open a notepad document which will show the activity of the user in the textbox. So far I do know how to save files into a text file as well open them. I also do know how to use the textChanged event for 2 textboxes but not with a text editing application like notepad. can someone help point me in the right direction and advise me on how to go about doing this. mind the lengthy text, hope I'm making sense :-)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do with Notepad here.  Are you trying to enter text into a running Notepad instance?  Why don't you just show the text in an application window instead?

Comment: I want the user input to show on notepad during runtime

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that, other than perhaps getting a handle to the Notepad window and sending keystrokes to it using some low-level Windows API.  But that seems like a whole lot of work just to display text.  There are native controls in the application which can display text.  You could just open a form with one large TextBox and write to that *a lot* more easily.

Comment: for example, textBox2.Text += textBox1.Text + Envionment.NewLine; would display whatever the user enters in textbox 1, in the 2nd textbox. Now I want to do exactly that but instead, show the input in a notepad text file

Comment: I guess you can look into some Windows APIs to try to send keystrokes and other commands to an application instance, and invoke an instance of Notepad as that application.  But, again, this is vastly more complicated than it needs to be.  As you've already shown, appending text to a TextBox is *one line of code*.  I see no reason why you need to use Notepad for this.  You can simply display the text in a form and write it to a text file.  You don't *need* to use Notepad to write to a text file, you can write to one in code.

Comment: Well I was just trying to get a lil' innovative and see if I could do something different, but thanks for the advise. will still try to see if I could make this work

Comment: Looks like Raymond Chen posted some code yesterday which pipes output into a Notepad instance: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/09/08/10555736.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can start a process using Sytem.Diagnostics.Process and then use SendKey.Send to send the text to the notpad window. Try this:

Add these api calls to your class:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll",EntryPoint="FindWindow")]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string sClass, string sWindow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Add this to your event handler (textbox.TextChanged/button.Clicked):

```
IntPtr notepadHwnd = FindWindow("Notepad",(string)null);
if (notepadHwnd == null)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Process notepad = new Process();
  notepad.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
  notepad.Start();
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
  notepadHwnd = FindWindow("Notepad",(string)null);
}
// get the text from the users input
string msg = textBox1.Text;
if (notepadHwnd != null)
{    
   SetForgroundWindow(notepadHwnd);

   // Send the string to the application that has focus 
   // note: If you need to erase existing text (ie. on TextChanged) 
   // you could use SendKeys.Send("^a{BACKSPACE}"); to select all and delete
   SendKeys.Send(msg);
}
```

Edit: Added FindWindow and SetForgroundWindow. This code assumes you don't have any other notepad windows open

Comment: I had used Process.Start("notepad.exe" , "path"); for the 1st 3 lines of your code, which both give me the same output I have been getting. it opens new multiple notepad files everytime I type something in the textbox. basically,' instead of reading the textbox input, it writes the input and ignores the textbox

Comment: I'm not following you. are you saying it opens notepad and then rewrites the text from textbox1.Text back to the textbox1?

Comment: I edited my answer to try and force notepad to be the active window in order for SendKeys to work.